# CHARINDEX issue with NULL CHAR variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @MyChar CHAR = NULL

SELECT  CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(NULL, '')),
        CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(@MyChar, '')),
        CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MyChar), ''))
```

The above query returns the values `0`, `1` and `0`, in that order.
This result should be `0`, `0` and `0`. Is this an issue with MS SQL or there is some functionality here which I haven't understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive this will answer the question:

```
DECLARE @MyChar CHAR = NULL

SELECT  CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(NULL, '')) a,
        CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(@MyChar, '')) b,
        CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MyChar), '')) c
```

Results:

```
a           b           c
----------- ----------- -----------
0           1           0
```

Testing the values:

```
SELECT  '|' + @MyChar + '|' a,
        '|' + ISNULL(@MyChar, '') + '|' b,
        '|' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MyChar), '') + '|' c
```

Results:

```
a    b    c
---- ---- --------------------------------
NULL | |  ||
```

The `ISNULL` method returns the data type of the first argument it receives. since `char` has a minimum length of 1, and will pad the value with trailing spaces if needed, the result of `ISNULL(@MyChar, '')` is a string with a single space, hence the 1 you get in your result.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to understand the second query in two parts.

First part: `SELECT ISNULL(@MyChar, '')`

As per MSDN regarding [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

> Data type determination of the resulting expression is determined based on the data type of the first parameter.

So your first parameter `@MyChar` which is of Char and its value is NULL and when you use it in ISNULL function, second parameter which is `''` (blank) will implicitly converted to CHAR like this -

`SELECT CAST('' AS CHAR)`

When you execute this query it'll give you whitespace.

Now when you execute your actual query with CharIndex

`SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', ISNULL(@MyChar, '')`

You'll get `1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the variable as CHAR and given the value as NULL hence it would occupy some space(2 bytes). So if the variable is a fixed width column and if you are trying to store NULL value in it then it will occupy the same amount of space as any other. From [here](http://www.sql-server-citation.com/2009/12/common-mistakes-in-sql-server-part-4.html):

> There is a misconception that if we have the NULL values in a table it
>   doesn't occupy storage space. The fact is, a NULL value occupies space
>   – 2 bytes

If you change the datatype to varchar(1) and then provide the value as NULL you will find that you are getting the result as 0,0,0. So in case of variable width provided to the variable the NULL takes no space.

A good read article: [How does SQL Server really store NULL-s](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx)